Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and AdGuard DNS doesn't work
I have AdGuard DNS and would use it with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
The Adguard DNS is: tls://xxxx.d.adguard-dns.com (where the xxxx is my Key)
I edited /etc/systemd/resolved.conf to
[Resolve]
DNS=tls://xxxx.d.adguard-dns.com
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
DNSSEC=yes
DNSOverTLS=yes
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no

After edit I did

systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service

But with this I have no Connection.
Without the tls:// it is the same, no Connection.
What do I have to do to get this working with my DNS?

This is something you may want to look up on the ADGuard site and see what they say. You also have failed to say what version of Ubuntu you are using.

I use Ubuntu 24.04 LTS i have it only i the title written, sorry.

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].
